# Django-I creating temp object and appending to list, overwrites whole list

Tags: django

I am trying to create temporary objects to a model and then append it to a list but the list keeps getting overwritten with the last value, is there a way to overcome this in django?

```
      for line in handle:
            k=Class_Output.make_object(line)
            miranda_entry.append(deepcopy(k))
            print (miranda_entry[0].query)
            print(miranda_entry[len(miranda_entry) - 1].query)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do this for?

Comment: I have a user defined csv file which i am trying to load on to memory and check before saving to db with bulk_create